# How to make bootable CDROM or USB from floppy?

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, startup, iso, cd-burning

I have a bootable floppy that boots just fine on old PCs.
I want to boot it however on my 2015 Macbook Pro, which does not have the BIOS (whereas my 2013 MBP did).
So I cannot on the 2015 model even boot a Linux CD.

I have an ISO header that will let me create a readable CDROM, but not a bootable CDROM. (Command is: cat isoheader.img floppy.img > cdrom.iso)

The Apple bless command gives an error when I add the --legacy switch.

What to do?

PS: I cannot use bootcamp as I do not have enough free drive space.

Comment: This question looks like an [x-y-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)! Which Linux distribution do you want to boot on your MBP 2015?

Comment: I want to boot MenuetOS.

Comment: Even if I could boot my Mac with it, I wouldn't! Just run it in  a virtual machine.

Comment: No I don't want to use a vm. I want a real solution.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you don't have the ISO use disk utility to take an image of your floppy.
2. Use the app from [etcher.io](http://etcher.io) to "burn" this ISO to a USB drive.

Now if the image itself is not bootable, that might be a better answered on a different stack-exchange.

Comment: I'd rather just generate it from the command-line. How do I know this Etcher doesn't have malware in it?

Comment: https://github.com/resin-io/etcher it's open source

Comment: Etcher doesn't build. It says: make: jq: Command not found

Comment: Etcher appear to be written in JS... bizarre.